# HTML/Javascript Drawing doesnt really want to work with the positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm making a control site for a drawing robot we have as a school project but the drawing function I want is not really working.

I know the site isn't made with a lot of care, but I just want the drawing function working properly.

I also have been having some problems with the JavaScript not recognizing the html elements so I have to call the function again manually with a button or an `onload=""` function.

The study I'm doing is more in JAVA and I've never had any education in proper JavaScript, HTML, or CSS design so dont judge me please.

My first thought was that the `canvasOffsetx` and `y` don't get the absolute position but relative from the parent div, so it's drawing on the wrong spot, but I really have no clue how to fix it or make that offset position absolute without messing up the entire css layout.

The portion of interest is in the "actions" div, the rest is not part of the problem

This is the github repository since it would be too large to give all the code here:
https://github.com/Masaslo/StackOverflowQuestions.git

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. And yes, you are judged. Please take more care in asking. Spell check your posts, ask ONE question using the minimum code needed to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `canvasOffsetX` and `Y` is relative to the parent. Don't set the canvas style and size to different values, because the image will be distorted, and you would also need to account for that when calculating the draw position. The drawing logic needed to be modified as well.

Remove the style from the canvas in the html:

```
- <canvas id="drawing-board" style="width: 502px; height: 502px;"></canvas>
+ <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
```

The fixed `canvasFuntion`:

```
function canvasFunction(){
    const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
    const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    const canvasOffsetX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const canvasOffsetY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;
    
    let isPainting = false;
    let lineWidth = 5;
    let startX;
    let startY;
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = 5;
    
  
    toolbar.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.id === 'clear') {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
    });
    
    
    const draw = (e) => {
        if(!isPainting) {
            return;
        }
    
        const canvasOffsetX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        const canvasOffsetY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX - canvasOffsetX, startY - canvasOffsetY);
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvasOffsetX, e.clientY - canvasOffsetY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        startX = e.clientX;
        startY = e.clientY;
    }
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        isPainting = true;
        startX = e.clientX;
        startY = e.clientY;
    });
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
        isPainting = false;
    });
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
    
}
```